# Как правильно — оледенение или обледенение?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов

Помогите разрешить спор. Учитель русского языка советской ещё школы утверждает, что слово "оледенение" (проводов, трасс и т. д.) — это единственно верное употребление, а вот "обледенение" — это девчушки вдоль трассы! Словари разнятся в толковании этого слова. Может быть, кто-то знает правило?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) Оледенеть — превратиться в лёд (сравнить: твёрдый — отвердеть, камень — окаменеть), в том числе в переносном смысле (замерзнуть, очень испугаться).
Ледниковый период — это оледенение.
Другой пример: "Оледенение, охватившее ее после гибели отца, постепенно прошло".

(2) Обледенеть — покрыться льдом. Обычно имеет место обледенение крыльев самолета, проводов, стекол.

Comment: София, согласно словарям, два варианта возможны.

Comment: Браво и спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 2):

Учитель не прав. Возможны оба варианта.

***ОБЛЕДЕНЕТЬ***, - ***Покрываться льдом со всех сторон, по всей поверхности.***
отт. ***Превращаться в лёд; замерзать.***

2.Становиться холодным как лёд; коченеть (Современный толковый словарь русского языка Ефремовой, 2000г.)
***ОБЛЕДЕНЕТЬ,*** -ею, -еешь; обледенённый; -нён, -нена, -нено; св.
1.
***Покрыться льдом***. Палуба обледенела. ***Мокрая дорога после оттепели обледенела.*** Валенки обледенели, и ноги разъезжались.
2.
***Замёрзнуть, закоченеть***. Руки обледенели. Губы на ветру обледенели. < Обледеневать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Обледенение, -я; ср. О. крыльев самолёта. Древнее о.( Большой толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова).

**Обледенение** - 
    ***отложение льда на поверхностях дорог, аэродромов, летательных аппаратов, морских судов и др.***( Энциклопедия техники).

***ОЛЕДЕНЕТЬ, -***нею, -неешь; оледеневший; св. (нсв. также леденеть).
1.
***Превратиться в лёд, покрыться льдом; обледенеть***. Мокрая одежда на морозе оледенела.
2.
***Стать холодным как лёд; замёрзнуть, окоченеть. От холодной воды руки оледенели. < Оледеневать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Оледенение, -я; ср.*** ( Большой толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова).

***ОЛЕДЕНЕНИЕ***

— оболочка льда и снега, включающая все виды О., известные на Земле. Основные типы О.:
    1) ***наземное — лед скапливается в виде ледников и ледниковых покровов;***
    2) морское — льды накапливаются на поверхности морей и океанов в виде однолетних и многолетних масс;(Геологическая энциклопедия).
    3) подземное (мерзлота).

Оледеневать

```
оледенева́ть
    несов. неперех.
    1.
    ***Покрываться льдом со всех сторон, по всей поверхности; превращаться в лед.***

    2.
    ***Становиться холодным, как лед; замерзать, коченеть.***

    3. перен.
    Цепенеть, холодеть от ужаса, страха и т.п.
```

Answer (score 1):

Сказать обводнение можно и звучит нормально.
Сказать оводнение  нельзя и звучит двусмысленно.

Вообще есть другая приставка, если холодно,  за-леденеть.

Обмерзнуть, замерзнуть, но не омерзнуть, можно сказать омерзительно, обмерзительно нельзя.

То есть оледенение-двоякий смысл, возможно, как результат вмешательства составителей словарей, а может и ученых, занимавшихся ВЕЛИКИМ ОЛЕДЕНЕНИЕМ, Оводнением хрусталика,не вполне знакомых с подобной спецификой русского языка.

Comment: Мне вот звучит нормально именно оледенение, именно оттого, что обледенение звучит двусмысленно на нынешний момент, этакая отсылка к обсценной лексике! Но это мои личные предпочтения и я признаю, что доводы, приведённые Софией очень убедительны, солидны и исчерпывающие для меня! Мне очень импонируют ваши опасения, я тоже так же рассуждала, как и вы, но приходится признать, что "обледенение" полноправный член русского языка, как бы это не звучало, особенно сейчас и из всех говорящих СМИ! Но, учитель русского языка советских времён остался непреклонен, увы! Спасибо всем огромное!

Comment: Видеть  в  обледенении  нечто  другое,  кроме  покрытия  льдом  -  это  больная  психика.